# css float: left clash/collision, how to avoid?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to use [Swipe JS 2](https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe/tree/swipe2) with jQuery Mobile (carefully taking into consideration the notes [here](https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe/issues/16)).

However, I find there is a problem with a clash of trying to use **float: left**. I can not interfere with the Swipe JS 2 references so the swipe motion on touch devices will work.

What this means is that the data that should be displayed in a grid, just gets displayed in a vertical column.

When examining the inspector for the CSS that should set the display to the grid I see the following:
[image]

**Note, it seems that inorder to see the slide motion it is only possible to do this on a touch device (mobile, tablet, etc).**

When you run the following, the swipe motion **works**, but the data **does not** display in a grid (code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u1sonderzug/YSGY3/, preview on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u1sonderzug/YSGY3/embedded/result/):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Slide</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css">
        <script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="https://raw.github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe/swipe2/swipe.js"></script>
        <style type='text/css'>
        /* Product CSS */
          
            .product {
            padding-top:10px;
            padding-bottom:10px;
            padding-left:24px;
            padding-right:24px;
            float:left;
        }
        /* Swipe 2 required styles */
        
            .swipe {
            overflow: hidden;
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        .swipe-wrap {
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }
        .swipe-wrap div {
            float:left;
            width:100%;
            position: relative;
        }
        </style>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $('#home').live('pageshow',function(){
                window.slider = new Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'));
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
          <div data-role="content">
            <!-- Take out the FOLLOWING two lines to display grid correctly -->
            <div id='slider' class='swipe'>
              <div class='swipe-wrap'>
                <!-- Take out the ABOVE two lines to display grid correctly -->
                <div>
                  <div class="product"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg/220px-NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg" /></div>
                  <div class="product"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg/220px-NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg" /></div>
                  <div class="product"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg/220px-NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg" /></div>
                  <div class="product"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg/220px-NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg" /></div>
                  <div class="product"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg/220px-NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg" /></div>
                  <div class="product"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg/220px-NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg" /></div>
                  <div class="product"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg/220px-NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg" /></div>
                  <div class="product"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg/220px-NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg" /></div>
                  <div class="product"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg/220px-NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg" /></div>
                  <div class="product"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg/220px-NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg" /></div>
                  <div class="product"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg/220px-NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg" /></div>
                  <div class="product"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg/220px-NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg" /></div>
                </div>
                <div><span><h1>This is the next page</h1></span></div>
                <!-- Take out the FOLLOWING two lines to display grid correctly -->
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Take out the ABOVE two lines to display grid correctly -->
          </div> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

​

When you run the following, the swipe motion **does not work**, but the data **does** display in a grid (code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u1sonderzug/JZQQY/, preview on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u1sonderzug/JZQQY/embedded/result/):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Slide</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css">
        <script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="https://raw.github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe/swipe2/swipe.js"></script>
        <style type='text/css'>
        /* Product CSS */
          
            .product {
            padding-top:10px;
            padding-bottom:10px;
            padding-left:24px;
            padding-right:24px;
            float:left;
        }
        /* Swipe 2 required styles */
        
            .swipe {
            overflow: hidden;
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        .swipe-wrap {
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }
        .swipe-wrap div {
            float:left;
            width:100%;
            position: relative;
        }
        </style>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $('#home').live('pageshow',function(){
                window.slider = new Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'));
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
          <div data-role="content">
           
                <div>
                  <div class="product"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg/220px-NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg" /></div>
                  <div class="product"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg/220px-NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg" /></div>
                  <div class="product"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg/220px-NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg" /></div>
                  <div class="product"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg/220px-NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg" /></div>
                  <div class="product"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg/220px-NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg" /></div>
                  <div class="product"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg/220px-NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg" /></div>
                  <div class="product"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg/220px-NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg" /></div>
                  <div class="product"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg/220px-NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg" /></div>
                  <div class="product"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg/220px-NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg" /></div>
                  <div class="product"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg/220px-NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg" /></div>
                  <div class="product"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg/220px-NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg" /></div>
                  <div class="product"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg/220px-NCI_Visuals_Food_Hamburger.jpg" /></div>
                </div>
                <div><span><h1>This is the next page</h1></span></div>
               
          </div> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your .product styles to add in a width: auto !important; line like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/b3Jyv/

```
 .product {
        padding-top:10px;
        padding-bottom:10px;
        padding-left:24px;
        padding-right:24px;
        float:left;
        width: auto !important;
    }
```

The div that contains each image is getting it's width set to 100% by the .swipe-wrap div set of style rules so there is no room for two products next to each other in the grid layout.

I can't work out how to change the window sizes on jsFiddle on my phone so I haven't managed to test it (there isn't enough room for two columns on the page as I look at it), but the above is the reason for the products appearing in a column so you should be able to work out a solution from there if this one doesn't work.